# "when" or "after" + "we had recently started dating"?

Tags: prepositions, time

What is the difference between *when* and *after* in the following examples?

> 1. I took my girlfriend to Niagara Falls **when** we had recently started dating.
> 2. I took my girlfriend to Niagara Falls **after** we had recently started dating.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 6):

The first sentence is correct, but might be clearer if you just rearranged to order of the phrases:

> we had recently started dating when I took my girlfriend to Niagara Falls.

[recently](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recently) means 'not long ago' - it is backward-looking.

[after](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/after) means a 'following in time' - it s forward-looking.

The second sentence uses both **recently** and **after**. **Recently** specifies a short period of time in the past, and **after** specifies an undefined time in the future. If you use both words in the same sentence, it creates a very strange image of the time sequence.

If you particularly want to use after, which is forward-looking, you need to express the short interval between the two events using a forward-looking word like **shortly** or **soon**, rather than the backward-looking **recently**.

> I took my girlfriend to Niagara Falls **shortly** after we had started dating.

Answer (score 2):

Both the sentences seem unusual and unidiomatic.

The conjunction "when"  also means *at the time that*, *as soon as*, or *just after*, so the adverb *recently* is superfluous here in light of these meanings. The sentence should be formed without *recently* as follows:

> I took my girlfriend to Niagara Falls when we had started dating

= I took my girlfriend to Niagara Hills at the time that/just after the time that/as soon as we started dating.

As for the second sentence, the usage of recently in the after-clause also doesn't seem appropriate.  Instead, we usually use shortly/just/immediately/soon before after as follows:

> I took my girlfriend to Niagara Falls shortly/just/soon/immediately after  we (had) started dating.

Answer (score -3):

So the difference is using when or after. I think the second one makes more sense, but any listener would know what you meant.